# Añadir una dependencia Maven

Tags: maven, jboss, dependencias

En mi pom.xml quiero añadir una dependencia, la cual sé que existe porque ha sido utilizada en otros proyectos, pero al introducirla en mi pom me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Missing artifact es.xunta.amtega.transversal.clientesws.sede:sede-electronica-client:jar:1.0.0
```

En caso de haber una solución alternativa, uso JBoss EAP 6.1.

He probado a añadir el jar al proyecto a mano, con `build path`, pero al ejecutar el programa no detecta la clase, da un ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: ¿Tienes añadido el repositorio igual ese pom que en los otros proyectos?

Comment: Sí, de hecho fue un copia pega.